# NULL when running remoteDriver()$navigate

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I'm trying to set up RSelenium to gather data from a website for a research project. I'm already struggling to set it up properly.

I have loaded RSelenium, rvest and httr and chromedriver is running

```
install.packages("pacman")
library(pacman)

p_load(RSelenium)
p_load(tidyverse)
p_load(rvest)
p_load(httr)
```

I set up my driver like this:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
  port = 9515L,  
  browserName = "chrome"
)
```

When i now try `remDr$open` I get the following:

```
> remDr$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
$id
[1] NA
```

When I try `remDr$navigate`, I get this outcome:

```
> remDr$navigate("https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Hauptseite")
NULL
```

I guess something is wrong with my driver setup, but I can't figure it out. I also tried using Firefox and geckodriver with the same results. Can anybody point me in the right direction?